# How to pass a shiny object into HTML file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I want to display the user name of the user in each tab. The Tab design is done using HTML and displayed in Shiny using the includeHTML() function.

The user's name should be displayed in the same tab panel rendered using an HTML file.

I want to pass the user name present in `input$login_id` into my HTML file stored in `www/` folder.

My effort so far,

In server.R

```
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("the_user_name", input$login_id)
  })
```

in HTML file

```
            <script>
              <h1> <span id = "name"></span> </h1>
              var userName = Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("the_user_name", function(value){
                return value;
              })
              document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = userName;
            </script>
```

I'm kinda new to it. So please do let me know if there is any better way of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      '
              Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("the_user_name", function(value){
                document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = value;
              })
      '
    ),
    tags$h1(tags$span(id = "name")),
    textInput("login_id", "Login ID")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("the_user_name", input$login_id)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Maybe the following part is problematic in your example?:

```
var userName = Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("the_user_name", function(value){
                return value;
              })
```

I have never seen returning value from `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` and reusing it in variable in any example, but I don't know JS enough to say if this is really a problem or something different makes your example not working. If I would have to guess, I would say that when the message (`session$sendCustomMessage("the_user_name", input$login_id)`) is send, only the code in the body of function in `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` is recomputed, so in your example *maybe* the following line of code is run only once (when the app / session starts): `document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = userName;` instead of everytime when `input$login_id` changes.